# run docker commands in non-interactive shell

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration

I'm running docker from Jenkins and the console output is not reflecting the actual state of operation because docker is using interactive shell.

How can I make docker output to stdout in non-interactive mode? (similar to mvn -B flag).

Thanks!

Comment: You can configure your logs to be written outside the container and access the logs directly

Comment: use volume docker : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Answer (score 0):

`--progress plain` should do the trick.